# using jQuery to add element in DOM after page content has fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick

It is easy to add text in page after loading thanks to javascript but I would like to add a link with a link  and be able to catch the click event without reloading page

```
$("#div").html("<a href='#' id='new'>new link</a>");


// not work, because no 
$("#new").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('click');
});
```

Do you know if there is a way ?

Comment: you need [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
$("#new").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('click');
});
```

with

```
$(document).on('click','#new',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('click');
});
```